# Want a class to run on a JPanel when I click a button

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel

I'm using NetBeans design mode to make a basic GUI. I have layered panels of equal size in the center of the app with buttons on either side These buttons `setvisible(false)` all panels and `setvisible(true)` the panel corresponding to the button (i.e. clicking the "team" button turns off all panels and turns on "team" panel etc).

My issue is that I want to instantiate a class on to each panel so as I can use inheritance to share information and use I/O as well as displaying any information.

Its a World Cup app where there are panels for each category, like teams, players, stadiums, fixtures etc. I'm learning how to use inheritance and want to be able to inherit players into teams and a few other things. Thanks in advance to anyone with suggestions.

Comment: I think you will get better responses if you explain a bit more clearly what exactly you want. Maybe a screenshot can help, too.

Comment: First of all, you will have to give us some relevant code, like how the JPanel is created. Also inheritance is an "is a" relationship, so it doesn't make sense to have a `Team` inherit from `Player` as a `Team` is not a `Player`.

Comment: Ask a specific question. Questions that infer _"help me design my application"_ are a little to broad for this sight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I'm using NetBeans design mode to make a basic GUI.

My first suggestion would be don't use GUI builders. Start reading [Swing tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) to learn how this API works and code your GUI classes by hand. It's fundamental learn about [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).

> These buttons setvisible(false) all panels and setvisible(true) the
>   panel corresponding to the button (i.e. clicking the "team" button
>   turns off all panels and turns on "team" panel etc).

Switching panels can be easily done using [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html). See [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) tutorial.

> I'm learning how to use inheritance and want to be able to inherit
>   players into teams and a few other things

Inheritance establishes an "is-a" relationship between two classes. Rarely a `Player` can be considered as a `Team`. Maybe you want to do something like this:

```
class Team {

    private List<Player> players;

    public void addPlayer(Player player) {...}

    public void removePlayer(Player player) {...};

    public List<Player> getPlayers() {...};
}
```

But this is not inheritance at all. Start reading [Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) article